# Can't use string IDs with Typescript in MongoDB driver

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I'm trying to update my node.js driver for MongoDb from 4.13 to 5.x or 6.x.  I'm using TypeScript.

For historical reasons, I'm using strings instead of BSON ObjectIDs for my document IDs.  When I upgrade, I get this error:

```
error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Condition<ObjectId>'.

136     await this.collection.updateOne({ _id: this.id }, [
                                          ~~~

  node_modules/mongodb/mongodb.d.ts:7381:5
    7381     _id: InferIdType<TSchema>;
             ~~~
    The expected type comes from property '_id' which is declared here on type 'Filter<Document>'
```

If I cast the ID value to "any", it compiles.

Is there a supported way to use string IDs?